# Update em Ajax apenas na linha selecionada

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, datatable

Eu tenho uma DataTable aqui e tô usando um plugin para que o usuário possa editar os dados da tabela, consegui em partes(haha), o problema é que minha call não está identificando o que o usuário entra, e quando eu defino manualmente o valor da célula ele altera em todas as linhas dessa coluna na db, imagino que eu precise identificar o ID da linha que o usuário está editando mas não sei como fazer.

Abaixo minha Ajax Call:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "include/edita.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { 'coletadora': 'Definição Manual'},                   
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);                                    
        }
    });
```

É relevante também o conteúdo da minha edita.php(ignorar o php defasado, tava a muito tempo longe do php e preciso desse sistema rodando antes de transicionar para PDO), sei que preciso de um WHERE para limitar o update a essa determinada ID que vamos descobrir:

```
    <?php
$host= 'localhost';
$bd= 'minhadb';
$userbd = 'meuusr';
$senhabd= 'meupw';



//Conectando com banco MySQL
$conexao = mysql_connect($host,$userbd,$senhabd);
if (!$conexao)
    die ("Erro de conexão com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());
//Conectando com a tabela do banco de dados
$banco = mysql_select_db($bd,$conexao);
if (!$banco)
    die ("Erro de conexão com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());
$coletadora   = $_POST["coletadora"];
$sql = "UPDATE minhadb SET coletadora = '$coletadora'";

mysql_query($sql,$conexao);
?>
```

Obrigado desde já pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

É por que você não informou, através do primary key ou outro valor único, qual a linha que deve ser alterada no banco de dados.

Uma saída para isso pode ser a inclusão do 'id' da linha alterada na requisição.

Por exemplo:
(levando em consideração que você usa jQuery)

```
<td data-id="1" data-coluna="coletadora">VALOR DA CÉLULA</td>
```

Quando o seu usuário submete as alterações, você deve incluir tanto a coluna e o novo valor quanto o "identificador" daquela linha, que, neste exemplo, seria a id.

Ex:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "include/edita.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { 
                $('tdQueOUserAlterou').data('coluna') : 
                $('tdQueOUserAlterou').text(),
                'id' : $('tdQueOUserAlterou').data('id')
        },                   
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);                                    
        }
    });
```

Então a query do SQL poderia ser alterada para:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE minhadb SET coletadora = '$coletadora' WHERE 'id'='$id'";
```

Essa tag WHERE é o que define qual a linha a ser alterada. Você quer setar o coletadora igual a tal valor APENAS onde o id for igual àquele informado. Lembrando que pode ser qualquer campo único na sua tabela e não somente id.

Comment: A lógica do processo eu tinha em mente, a dificuldade em aplicar tá no fato de que essa DataTable é gerada a partir de um SELECT na minha db, sendo assim não consigo acertar a sintaxe da jquery para capturar a ID da linha que estou editando. O que pode me ajudar é o fato de que a id da linha é mostrada como "Protocolo" pro usuário consultar depois o agendamento, foi um atalho que peguei, mas não sei como utilizar isso a meu favor, se é que será necessário.

Comment: Dá uma olhada em como é formada a tabela @victormoraesgs : http://pasted.co/ed579cd4

Comment: @FernandoGross Você pode colocar a $row['id'] como uma propriedade de cada td daquela linha.

Comment: @FernandoGross uma outra possibilidade que pensei agora, é dar um name pra cada <td> com a sua respectiva coluna, `<td name="id">$row['id']</td>`, isso faz com que você possa selecionar aquela célula a partir da célula editada: `$('tdEdidata').siblings('td[name="id"]').text();` isso traria o id daquela linha para a sua requisição AJAX.

Comment: Ex: [http://pasted.co/1c770c6f](http://pasted.co/1c770c6f)

Comment: Opa, no teu primeiro exemplo eu tive o tino de fazer depois da tua primeira resposta ontem, só não soube como fica o Ajax pra que o usuário possa alterar as células Coletadora, Data Coleta e Hora Coleta apenas pra id da row que ele selecionou, acho que falta só isso mesmo. Já no teu código o problema foi que ficou todo fora de ordem a tabela, não tá respeitando a ordem das th, com algum estudo dá pra ordenar,

Comment: Código da alteração que eu havia feito: http://pasted.co/66b90f36

Comment: @FernandoGross O único problema do seu exemplo é como você nomeou as tags, por exemplo: <td id="coletadora".... A id de um elemento deve ser única, portanto, não se pode usar a id coletadora para várias células diferentes (já que tem várias linhas). Me responda uma coisa, como vai funcionar a edição da sua tabela? Existe um botão Salvar centralizado que salva todas as linhas ou um botão salvar por linha?

Comment: Olha a call do Ajax como tá no momento: http://pasted.co/43edc2f8 Ela envia tudo como tu pode ver.

Comment: No momento em que o usuário clica na célula que quer editar abre um campo pra digitar o novo valor, com um botão para confirmar e outro para cancelar, dá pra ele clicar em mais de uma célula ao mesmo tempo(outro campo se abre a cada célula editável clicada), segundo deu pra ver no Firebug ainda que ele clique "confirmar" em uma só das células ele envia os dados de todas as células que eu determinei editáveis, imagino que se o usuário não alterou uma célula que abriu ele envia o dado atual da célula.